# Android Parsing Date from String

Tags: java, android, android-studio, simpledateformat

This is my code which I used to parse Date from String:

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");
      Date date;
      try {
             date = df.parse(myButton.getText().toString()); //Button Text: Remind on: 15 SEP 2017 ( 10:10 ) PM
             String newDateString = df.format(date);
             String tempDate = newDateString;
             Log.d("","Test Date Parsed: "+ tempDate);
          } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

But Log.d does not called when app is running. I want to save my button text to tempData like this: 15 09 2017
But try catch not called

Comment: try with format `dd MM yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

instead of this

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");
```

Comment: Sorry to say, your solution doesn't working...

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
I think it is problem with a pattern. You use "**yyyy MMM dd**" which corresponds to 2015 09 15 date format. Please try "**dd MM yyyy**"